# geometry: distance of center point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am trying to calculate the distance of the center point from a fixed point shown in the attached image. Please suggest me the calculation procedure for the marked dimension with "?".
Thank you very much[Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHHRF.jpg)

Comment: It is very difficult to understand anything from the image you have provided. Please insert the image into the question and give a short summary of the question so that we can make out the meaning of that image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have all the necessary measures to find the red angle.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Seyed for your answer. It is really helpful . However I am trying to draw the profile using program, so is there any feasibility to write 'z' in terms of existing Lengths and x alone? Please suggest

Comment: since Greenline dimension will not be in terms of L or x

Comment: @Ushay, yes green line times cosine of its angle is equal to x. Therefore green line is equal to x divided by cosine of the angle.

Comment: Thank you very much @Seyed